# SSMS 2008 R2 - Clear clipboard after copying and pasting result set

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

Is there a way within SQL Server Management Studio for SQL Server 2008 R2 to clear the clipboard of result set items you've copied?  I've been doing a lot of copy and pasting of large result sets, and each time I copy them it adds to the memory SSMS is taking up, and it ends up crashing after a while.

I realize there's a better way to do this (ie. don't copy and paste - pipe the data directly to where it should be going) but I can't find a solution to clearing the SSMS clipboard and now it's bothering me.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is most probably not the clipboard, but simply general behavior of .NET Garbage collector. And there is nothing to do about it. But hey, it is 2019 today and you can use more recent version of the SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

You actually clear it every time you copy something new. So when you copy 1 char you already have cleared the clipboard. The reason for crashes might be in memory management of SSMS - it does not mean that memory if released immediately when you copy 1 char.

But maybe there is another solution for your problem. Where do you copy data to ? Another application ? Excel ? Text file ? If you tell your scenario there might be a better solution for it.

Comment: I've noticed some drop in the memory allocation of SSMS when I copy a new piece of data - but it still keeps adding up and is not consistent.  For example, I haven't done any copy/pasting in my current SSMS instance and I'm at ~100MB.  Pulling a 2.7M row dataset into the result window increases memory by ~50MB, and copying/pasting (into excel) ~9K of those rows increased usage by 60MB.  Then trying to copy a single cell or a row from the original result window at this point did not change the memory usage.

Comment: Unfortunately that is the way it is in SSMS. SSMS does not load all data into grid and shows only kind of "preview". The rest resides on disk cache. If you copy big amount of data to clipboard SSMS has to reserve the full required amount but garbage collector does not release it then back for some reason (it happens sometimes after several minutes).

Comment: I develop SSMSBoost add-in for SSMS and faced that problem implementing grid scripter. As a result we had to switch to own disk-cache to solve the problem (query data in small portions). SSMSBoost might solve your problem, as far as we have implemented export to excel using native XML spreadsheet format. Really big data amounts should be possible.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into SSMSBoost.  I can always also just use the native Data Connections in Excel, but I like using SSMS to get everything set up, etc.